# Gelfand triple: what happens if we don't identify the pivot Hilbert space with its dual?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, banach-spaces

People usually say $V \subset H = H^* \subset V^*$ is a Gelfand triple if $V$ is continuously and densely embedded in $H$ and $H$ is identified with its dual.

Sometimes they do not mentioned that $H$ is identified with its dual.  See Zeidler, section 23.4, where every $h \in H$ is identified with $\bar h \in V^*$ where $\langle \bar h, v \rangle_{V^*,V} := (h, v)_H$.

What goes wrong if we do not identify $H$ with its dual?  Of course I understand that $H^* \subset V^*$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The isomorphism $H \to H^*$ is always there, whether you pay attention to it or not. Making it explicit would be annoying; it would be akin to disallowing yourself to treat a rational number as if it were a real number, and having to add extra notation whenever you want to convert a rational number to its corresponding real number.